# Instantiating a contract with ether

Tags: solidity, payable, address.transfer

I have a factory contract that I need to be able to deploy with some ETH. I'm getting an error `TypeError: Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address.`

I tried instantiating the contract address as payable but not having any luck.

Where am I going wrong?

## Factory contract

```
function createContract() public payable {
   NewContract myNewContract = new NewContract();
   address newContractAddress = address(newContract);
   newContractAddress.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

The following also doesn't work:

```
function createContract() public payable {
   NewContract myNewContract = new NewContract();
   address payable newContractAddress = address(newContract);
   newContractAddress.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

## Constructed contract

```
constructor() public payable {
   ...
}
```

Comment: "The following also doesn't work" - with the exact same error??

Comment: different error: `Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable` @goodvibration

Comment: Well, then simply change `address(newContract)` to `address payable(newContract)`.

Comment: @goodvibration That's not how you cast to `address payable`. The way to get an `address payable` is to cast it to an integer, then cast it to an address: `address(uint160(newContract))`

Answer (score 1):

You made your constructor payable, but that only means you can attach funds to the contract creation expression:

```
NewContract myNewContract = (new NewContract).value(msg.value)();
```

To make it possible to transfer ETH to a contract add a payable fallback function:

```
function () external payable
{
}
```

You can only use `.transfer(..)` on a value of type `address payable`. To convert an `address` to an `address payable`, cast to `uint160` then back to `address`:

```
address payable b = address(uint160(a));
```

Attaching the ETH to the contract creation transaction is more efficient than creating with 0 ETH and then transferring the ETH.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The error means you are trying to use a function transfer() which does not apply to the type address.

It can only be used on an address payable.